# Javascript date validation time error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to validate that a string put into a date field is in fact a valid date.

The issue was someone accidentally removed the colon from the time part, so using `Date.parse(dateStr)`
allowed me to sort that, but now they found that if they have a date like:

31 July 11:30v
when I do the Date.parse(dateStr) it seems to accept the letter v and I get a different time and a date of 31 July 03:30

so is there a definitive way to check for a valid date that can be entered in any format?

Comment: In *any* format? No. In your example, `Date.parse("1")` works too, as do any number of other "false positives". [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) provides overloads for parsing in a given format

Comment: aha of course, sorry having a dim day today, just tried adding moment.js but when i try to call the moment method it errors with undefined hmm i hate this..

Comment: @grenadier181 - that seems unrelated to what you asked, and I'm not sure how to help you without supporting details.

Comment: My fix turned out to be something else entirely, but thanks for the input it was helpful